# How to use GROUP BY in an efficient way without losing attributes?

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, subquery, group-by, query-performance

*I am working with PostgreSQL.*

My idea is to group players who appear more than 3 times in **table-a**.

**table-a =** <**player_id, year_world, c, d, e**>

With the first subquery I get **player_id** and the number of times that player played a world cup.
And with the `NATURAL JOIN` I recover the year or other attributes in the tuples that player appears.

The following query works but I want to optimize it:

```
SELECT player_id , year_world
FROM    (SELECT player_id , count(player_id ) player_id_count
        FROM <table-a> 
        GROUP BY player_id 
        HAVING count(player_id ) > 3) playersMoreThree
NATURAL JOIN <table-a>
```

I would like to know if it is possible not to use the `NATURAL JOIN` to obtain the other attributes of the table. Because when I put the rest of the attributes I want to project into `SELECT` and in the`GROUP BY` I get an empty table.

> Keep in mind that the attribute that is added to the `SELECT` of the subquery of the `GROUP BY` has to be determined by the attribute that we are grouping. That is, for each **player_id** value, I can always have the same value of the new attribute, if for a same value of **player_id** I have different values of the new attribute, this is not determined. For add an attribute that is not correlated by what group I use `NATURAL JOIN` or another solution.

The following query without `NATURAL JOIN` does not work for me:

```
SELECT player_id, count(player_id ) player_id_count, year_world, c, d, e
FROM <table-a> 
GROUP BY player_id, year_world, c, d, e
HAVING count(player_id ) > 3
```

What would be the most efficient way in DML?

Comment: Put the rest of the attributes in the `SELECT` list only of the main query. The `GROUP BY` subquery should remain unchanged.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `natural join` should be avoided, you should explicitly state your join columns.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Could you write me how the consultation would be? Because if I add the year_world attribute in the SELECT of the subquery the server asks me to also go in the GROUP BY; On the other hand, if I add the attribute in the external query, I need the NATURAL JOIN or JOIN conditional, otherwise the 'attribute does not exist'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, from now on I will cross the tables with explicit conditions: JOIN ... ON

Comment: If the question is how to do this in the most efficient way, then please edit the question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement and all the indexes on the table.

Comment: I'm looking for efficiency in DML @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: @ITDevelopers yes, so we'll need the `CREATE TABLE` and indexes for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add more columns in the `SELECT` of the main query, without changing the subquery at all:

```
SELECT player_id , year_world, c, d, e                   -- all columns
FROM    (SELECT player_id , count(player_id ) player_id_count
        FROM <table-a> 
        GROUP BY player_id 
        HAVING count(player_id ) > 3) playersMoreThree
NATURAL JOIN <table-a>
```

Whether you do a `NATURAL` join or a `JOIN .. ON` doesn't matter for efficiency (but using a `LATERAL` join may do matter).

The other common method would be using window functions in a subquery or CTE and then restricting the result with a `WHERE` in the main query - exactly what Lennart's answer does.

In any case, the problem needs some kind of subquery to be solved.

For efficiency, an index on `(player_id)` is very likely to help, with either method you write the query. Memory settings, like `work_mem` should also be examined and can affect performance. Optimal settings and efficiency depend on many things (size of the tables, data distribution, RAM size of the whole server, number of connections, version of Postgres, etc.)

It could very well be that the solution with the join on the `GROUP BY` result (or the `LATERAL` variation) is more efficient than the solution using window functions. This depends largely on your data distribution and the indexes available. You have to compare the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for all methods.

Comment: I think he wants to avoid the self-JOIN.

Comment: I know, but my idea is to eliminate the subquery and the NATURAL JOIN

Comment: @Lennart ah. I read the question as " it is possible to use the NATURAL JOIN ..."

Comment: @ITDevelopers: it could very well be that the solution with the join on the GROUP BY result is more efficient than the solution using window functions. This depends largely on your data distribution and the indexes available. You have to compare the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for both solutions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thnx. Added in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT player_id , ... FROM (
    SELECT player_id, year_world, ...
         , COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY player_id) AS player_id_count
    FROM <table-a> 
) AS T
WHERE player_id_count > 3
```

`over (partition by player_id)` defines the window where `count(*)` should be applied. In this case, we want the window to be all rows for the player in question. This means that you will get the count for player_id on all rows with player_id.

Comment: I still can not vote but this works. Thank you.
Why do you use the first FROM in lowercase?

Comment: No particular reason. SQL is case insensitive so it does not matter, but I'll update it.

Comment: I knew it but I thought you used some convention. Is there any way to do the same using GROUP BY or HAVING in a performant way?

Comment: Not really. The `GROUP BY` clause needs to functionally determine the `SELECT` clause, so you'll lose some attributes in your new relation.